# Programa de java para login de usuario

Tags: java, array, funciones, contador

Tengo un problema, a la hora de contar los usuarios registrados cuando el metodo loguearUsuario da true quiero que se sume en 1, pero al consultar de nuevo pero sin crear o loguear ningun usuario se sigue sumando el contador.... no se como puedo encarar este error.
Entiendo que una vez que el metodo da true el contador sigue sumando, mi duda es como hacer que cuente cada vez que un usuario haga un log in solamente.

```
public boolean loguearUsuario(String nombre, String pass) {
    this.nombreEnSistema = nombre;
    this.passEnSistema = pass;
    for (int i = 0; i < userAIngresar; i++) {
        if (listaUser[i].getNombre().equals(nombre) && listaUser[i].getContraseña().equals(pass)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public int cantidadUsuarios() {

    if (loguearUsuario(nombreEnSistema, passEnSistema) == true) {
        this.cantidadDeUsuariosLogueados++; 
    }
    return cantidadDeUsuariosLogueados;
}
```

Comment: Crea una variable boolean en tu método loguearusuario e inicializa en false, luego que cambie en true o false.

Comment: Genial, ambas respuestas me sirvieron para orientarme, por ahora me contabiliza cada vez que hago log in con un usuario creado y no cada vez que elijo esa opcion.

Answer (score 0):

porque no intentas sacar el `for` y los vas sumando conforme lo vaya encontrando el

```
 if (listaUser[i].getNombre().equals(nombre) && listaUser[i].getContraseña().equals(pass)) {}
```

o mejor aun mete ese usuario y password una lista indicando que ya esta contabilizado, `lista.add(nombre+"-"+pass)` y luego comparas si ya existe allí, para no hacer la suma.